# WSDL and F# TypeProviders in mono

Tags: f#, mono, wsdl, fsharp.data.typeproviders

After having used the FSharp.Data TypeProviders in several different projects working on JSON I was look for a similar approach to consuming WSDL based services. Seeing [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156503.aspx) example I was hopefull. Unfortunately that doesn't work using mono on a Mac.

Are there any alternatives or solutions to the error

```
"The type provider 
'FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.DesignTime.DataProviders' reported an error: 
The .NET SDK 4.0 or 4.5 tools could not be found (FS3033)"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is written with very little knowledge of mono, but some knowledge of this WSDL type provider. I use it a lot and have some experience in all the quirks, including reading the source of it to try to understand what has happened where and why from time to time. Add also some knowledge of the svcutil-tool in general and the bugs and what not of this sub par tool.

I guess the main problem here is that the "path" to svcutil on mono is wrong or svcutil is missing entirely. Or a permutation of that problem like missing some registry key for pointing to svcutil path.

On the other hand I do think that svcutil should be available also on mono.

The WSDL provider is an non-erasing type provider and generates a proxy by using the svcutil for generating code and then compiling it. Making sure you have the svcutil available and then making sure its in path/registry/whatever, MIGHT help you. Otherwise, Im 99% sure, you will not be able to use this type provider on mono unfortunately. The unsure part here is if you generate a library in a windows environment, and then reuse this dll, within mono, that might work.

Looking at the source at github: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/blob/master/src/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/Util.fs#L106 (line 106++)
and
https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/blob/master/src/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/TypeProviders.fs (parts where SvcUtil is used)
you might get a clue as to where, how and what not, to make sure the SvcUtil.exe is available at correct paths.

https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/blob/master/src/FSharp.Data.TypeProviders/Util.fs#L82 does reference a few registry keys and also adds a few paths hard coded.

Hopefully that might fix it for you by making sure you actually have the svcutil at "correct" path...

I do not like this dependency on svcutil (it has bit me too *grrr*), or other external tools in the type providers, in general, and hopefully some kind soul will embark on a mission to rewrite this at some time.